# How Can I Make This Start Button Load My Game?

Tags: python, pygame

I made a menu start game and quit game I am really confused on how to put my main loop in a function and call that function when I click the button please help! I tried to put my main loop in a def funtion  but my screen will appear black and nothing shows up here is an image of my start menu  [Video](https://gyazo.com/1a324cd29aae90a76f5514eb76aef0d1)
my full code [script](https://pastebin.com/UMvY3MMZ)

this is my  game intro

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def game_intro():
    red = (200,0,0)
    green = (0,200,0)
    bright_red = (255,0,0)
    bright_green = (0,255,0)

    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        window.fill((255,255,255))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('BLOODY.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Stolen Hearts!", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((800/2), (800/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

# make the square brighter if collideded with the buttons
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if 150+120 > mouse[0] > 150 and 450+50 > mouse[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, bright_green,(150,450,120,50))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, green,(150,450,120,50))
        if 550+110 > mouse[0] > 550 and 450+50 > mouse[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, bright_red,(550,450,110,50))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, red,(550,450,110,50))
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Start Game", smallText)
        textRect.center = ( (150+(120/2)), (450+(50/2)) )
        window.blit(textSurf, textRect)


        smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Quit Game", smallText)
        textRect.center = ( (150+(910/2)), (450+(50/2)) )
        window.blit(textSurf, textRect)


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a boolean called `main_hover`, and set it to false. Set it to true when the mouse is over the play button. If it isn't, set it to false.
In your event for loop, you will want to add this:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    if main_hover == True:
        main_loop()
```

Do the same, but for the quit button.
Your code should look like this:

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def game_intro():
    red = (200,0,0)
    green = (0,200,0)
    bright_red = (255,0,0)
    bright_green = (0,255,0)

    intro = True
    main_hover = False
    quit_hover = False
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if main_hover == True:
                   main_loop()
                if quit_hover == True:
                   quit()

        window.fill((255,255,255))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('BLOODY.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Stolen Hearts!", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((800/2), (800/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

# make the square brighter if collideded with the buttons
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if 150+120 > mouse[0] > 150 and 450+50 > mouse[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, bright_green,(150,450,120,50))
            main_hover = True
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, green,(150,450,120,50))
            main_hover = False
        if 550+110 > mouse[0] > 550 and 450+50 > mouse[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, bright_red,(550,450,110,50))
            quit_hover = True 
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, red,(550,450,110,50))
            quit_hover = False
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Start Game", smallText)
        textRect.center = ( (150+(120/2)), (450+(50/2)) )
        window.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

Hope this helps